# Laravel 4.2 - exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Cannot redirect to an empty URL.'

Tags: laravel-4, http-referer

For a client I am trying to add a route to a Laravel 4.2 site that loads all sort of packages. The route should save a name and email address that is posted to it from a router.

It uses models that use various packages and I am guessing that in one of them the method

```
Redirect::back();
```

is called. The router HTTP header doesn't provide a url in

```
HTTP_REFERER
```

So I am getting the exception:

> exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Cannot redirect to an empty URL.'

I don't want to mess with the packages, so is there any way I can set the HTTP_REFERER header before the packages are loaded?